# Proper structure and run configurations for a Spring Boot maven project using JUnit and Cucumber

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, junit, cucumber

I am building a Spring Boot API as a maven project which is structured like this:

```
main-project-folder/

  - pom.xml

  - api-module/
    - pom.xml
    - src/
      - main/: models, controllers, JPA repositories, service layers, etc
      - test/: My unit tests running with JUnit 5 (dependency of spring-boot-starter-test 2.7.7)

  - acceptance-test-module/ (my cucumber tests)
    - pom.xml (specifies the api-module as a dependency)
    - src/test/
      - java/
        - runner class using JUnit @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
        - config class with @CucumberContextConfiguration and autoconfigured test DB using H2
        - step definitions
      - resources/
        - feature files
        - application.yaml
```

This is my first time working with spring boot and cucumber, and in the past several months on this project I'm still not clear on how to properly integrate the two. While writing acceptance tests, I've spent a lot of time trying to troubleshoot various issues related to H2 database setup/teardown, rebuilding maven modules, and setting up run configurations for testing. For example, right now my only way to run my acceptance tests is to run my Runner class (which runs all tests every single time), and any time I want to make a change to a step definition I have to mvn clean install the module again.

I get the feeling a lot of the issues I encounter stem from some underlying flaw in the way this project is set up. For reference, I have only ~1.5 years worth of full-time experience in the field. I wouldn't be posting this here if I hadn't already spent way too much time trying to find guidance/documentation for my specific situation, so I'm hoping someone here has either worked on something similar before or can point me in the right direction to better understand the integration of spring boot and cucumber. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the setup that you have posted. You don't have to run Cucumber in a separate module though. For JUnit 5 you should use `cucumber-junit-platform-engine` and remove the `cucumber-junit` dependency. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine

Comment: You can also look at https://github.com/mpkorstanje/cucumber-spring-boot-parallel (though you won't need the junit-bom, spring boot already includes it).

Comment: Selecting individual tests can be done through the JUnit 5 suite annotations: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.platform.suite.api/org/junit/platform/suite/api/package-summary.html

Comment: If you use a half decent IDE you can also run by clicking run buttons in a feature file.

Comment: Not much else I can say. It would help if your made your problems more concrete and reproduced them in a small project. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example